# Plotting future uncertainty on line graph with ggplot in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, uncertainty, geom-ribbon

I am looking for a way in ggplot to plot an historic line of data which then merges into a shaded area representing future uncertainty (like the GHG emissions graphs below - but at the moment I just want one trajectory into the future - and even then based simply on straight lines).

This is the historic data line I want:

Quarter historicData

1:  2022Q3      1.91626

2:  2022Q2      1.78145

3:  2022Q1      1.66113

4:  2021Q4      1.47459

I then want to have a "wedge" going from a single point of 1.91626 at 2022Q3, spreading to a maximum of 47 and a minimum of 37 at 2029Q4

I have looked at geom_ribbon but this appears only to do a constant width?

Could anyone help me please?
Many thanks,
Tim

[image: Future uncertainty bounds]

Comment: *"I have looked at geom_ribbon but this appears only to do a constant width?"* That is incorrect.

Comment: Put your data in a format so you have separate columns for the minimum and maximum y values for each x value, then use `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin = your_min_column, ymax = your_max_column))`

Comment: I have tried this
> target

        x       y1       y2

1: 2022Q3  1.91626  1.91626

2: 2029Q4 37.12000 46.77000

ggplot()+ geom_ribbon(data=target,aes(x = x, ymin = y1, ymax = y2),fill = "red")

But this isn't working

Comment: Thanks very much - I have sorted it - my problem was the Quarter format of my dates was leading to a problem with the x-axis